# Webpack et React 16: Failed to compile. ./node_modules/style-loader/lib/addStyles.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, webpack

I'm building an App using **React 16.4.2**, unfortunately I've got this error message after installing **Bootstrap 4** (via `npm: np install bootstrap`):

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/style-loader/lib/addStyles.js

Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\open\Desktop\react-app\contactmanager\node_modules\style-loader\lib\addStyles.js'
```

This is my App.js file (where I import bootstrap):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Contact from "./component/Contact";
import Header from "./component/Header";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Contact name="My Name" email="XXX@gmail.com" phone="+XXX XXX XXX" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

*By the way, I only have two components: Header and Contact.*

Any Idea Please?

Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing all dependencies? `rm -rf ./node_modules && npm install`

Comment: It works. Thank you. But I dont know why !!!?

Comment: Great! It's can happen for a lot of reasons and it's hard to say after the fact, but it looks like your `style-loader` installation was corrupt. It might be that you accidentally aborted an install, etc.

Answer (score 10):

It looks like your `style-loader` installation is corrupt. It will most likely be resolved if you just remove your dependencies and install them from scratch.

```
rm -rf ./node_modules && npm install
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue but deleting node_modules and reinstalling did not help.

'style-loader' was still missing and I have to manually install it via 'npm install style-loader', then stop and restart the React application.

I used create-react-app, with the following versions:

"bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
"react": "^16.6.3",
"react-dom": "^16.6.3",
"react-scripts": "2.1.1"